# Cant' find a proper way to display json to html

Tags: angular, data-binding

so I tried hard to find any solution for this before I asked.

I have a huge and pretty random json, like it's not that random but sometimes you can get it with or without specific fields and sometimes the fields are nested with different types of data (sometimes can be array/string/another object and so on..)

after some reading online about angular pipes I just tried to create a html template with pipe inside to render the data from the json and it works but..

I want to render the data for example this json:

```
[
    {
        "id": "XXX",
        "version": 1,
        "head": {
            "text": "Main title",
            "sub": {
                "value": "next"
            },
            "place": "secondary"
        },
        "body": [
            {
                "id": "XXX1",
                "info": "three little birds",
                "extended": {
                    "spl": {
                        "text": "song",
                        "type": {
                            "value": "a"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "XXX2",
                "info": [
                    "how are you?"
                ],
                "extended": {
                    "spl": {
                        "text": "just"
                        "non-type": {
                            "value": "abc"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

to make it display in html sort of like:

```
<div class="head">
  <div *ngFor="let head of heads">
    <span class="headTitle">
      <h3>{{Head Title}}</h3>
    </span>

    <div *ngFor="let sub of subs">
      <span>[{{sub-value}}]&nbsp;</span>
    </div>

    <div *ngFor="let place of places">
      <span>{{place}}&nbsp;</span>
    </div>

    <div *ngFor="let body of bodys">
      <div class="extended">
        <div class="spl">
          <span>{{text}}&nbsp;</span>
          <span>{{type}}&nbsp;</span>
          <span>{{non-type}}&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

with the possibility to grab the data in same order although if its array or object inside the field! as I said it can be with lot of variations nested so I need to write validator for each kind. but how do I control the display of the data? split into pieces to render

Comment: I'm afraid it would be best to make this manually by building HTML template around it.

Comment: Ok.. but how? I have error type everytime I  want to display item

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the object displayed in JSON (without formatting), you can use Angular's [json pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe).

If you want to pretty print the JSON (with the break lines/indentations), you will have to implement it yourself/use a package. 
A simple pretty pipe can be done in the following manner (just came up with it):

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'prettyjson'
})
export class PrettyJsonPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return JSON.stringify(value, null, 4)
    .replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;')
      .replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
  }

}
```

Then use it in your template as follows

```
<div [innerHTML]="myJSON | prettyjson"></div>
```

Comment: No thanks. I know this json pipe. this is not what I want to do.. I want to have a specific div/span for every value in the json